# Azure Route Point-to-Site client traffic to Site-to-Site on-premise network

Tags: azure, routes, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

all. I created a site-to-site and point-to-site vpn connection to my Windows AzureRM VNet. I am wondering is it possible to allow the point-to-site vpn clients to access the site-to-site vpn on-premise network by connecting to Azure VNet only ? I couldn't find related article or tutorial on this. I think it's kind of impossible too based on my little knowledge on Windows Azure networking.

Can anyone give me some idea ? Is it possible to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To connect a P2S client to your on premises network via P2S VPN and Azure VPN gateway, there are some changes you need to do:

1. Add a route on your on premises VPN device for the VPNClientAddressPool pointing to the IPsec tunnel
2. Add a route on your P2S client for your on premises address range pointing to the P2S VPN tunnel on the client (you can use the address on the PPP interface as the nexthop)

Traffic should flow after you do these two steps. Basically, Azure gateways and P2S client package only include the VNet prefixes and P2S VPN client prefixes. So you need to manually those ranges specified above to the on premises VPN devices and P2S clients respectively.

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]